# How does one update JSON data on a Node.js server from a webpage on a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I am trying to make a website where a user can input a string which gets added to a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
[
  "Here is a thing",
  "Here is another thing",
  "No more things please"
]
```

What I want to happen: If a user were to input something like `Pancakes`, the JSON file would look like:

```
[
  "Pancakes",
  "Here is a thing",
  "Here is another thing",
  "No more things please"
]
```

I have been unsuccessful in making `things.unshift(newThing);` work because this only makes changes within the browser's copy of the JSON. Changes can't be made, as other posts on stackoverflow have said, to the JSON file on the Node.js server since doing that is dangerous (security considerations). How should I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: can you expose an api on your Node.js server that will take in the user's input and add it to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Changes can't be made, as other posts on stackoverflow have said, to the JSON file on the Node.js server since doing that is dangerous (security considerations).

That's nonsense.  If you want to update data stored on the server, then naturally you have to update the data stored on the server.  If you could cite where you saw this, we could point out what's wrong with the answer, or where the confusion is in your interpretation.

Your Node.js server can save to disk whatever you'd like.

Normally, from the client you would make a simple Fetch call.  Something like this:

```
fetch('/data', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Then on your server, the data storage can be as simple or as complex as you need it.  You could even do `fs.writeFile('data.json', req.body)`.  The specifics of what you do depend on the specifics of what you need.  And, don't forget to authenticate your users!  It is important that not just anyone can change anyone else's data.